# Flutter version 3.3.2 on channel unknown at D:\flutter Upstream repository unknown

Tags: flutter, dart, terminal, flutter-doctor, flutter-upgrade

So I want to upgrade flutter version, but when I run `flutter doctor`, this error appears

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[!] Flutter (Channel unknown, 3.3.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2130], locale en-GB)
    ! Upstream repository unknown
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Professional 2019 16.4.5)
      workload, and include these components:
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.73.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Then when I run the `flutter upgrade` command, this error appears.

```
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MuhammadFaisalIchal/Flutter-Travel-Pesawat-App.git/' not found
  Command: git fetch --tags
```

I know, this might be because the repository url is stuck at that web address, but I don't know how to fix it.
I don't know why the repository is stuck on the web address of the repository, because I've already deleted the repository.

How to solve this?
Thanks for any advice or solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix it, although currently I can do debugging and development without any problems in version `3.3.2`, but in the long term there will definitely be problems, so I decided to fix it as soon as possible.

What I did was to update the Flutter SDK files residing in my locale to the latest version, which you can get [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#get-the-flutter-sdk).

1. Rename the current Flutter SDK folder to another name (*for backup purposes*) example: `D:\fluttersdk` to `D:\fluttersdk_backup`
2. You may not be able to rename it directly because this folder is used by some programs, you can follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJv0hwPhlag) to solve it.
3. **Use the dynamic stable version** that comes from the Github repository as the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#get-the-flutter-sdk) says
4. You may encounter the error if you are using a Git repository,
   `fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at 'D:/flutter' 'D:/flutter/.git' is owned by:`, then you can solve it by using the command `git config --global --add safe.directory D:/flutter` as suggested by the error terminal
5. Run `flutter doctor`
6. Run `flutter pub get`

If there are no problems, you should be able to immediately develop the application again like the beginning

Answer (score 0):

In my case, not git for windows
Error caused by executing C:\cygwin64\bin\git

When an error occurs

```
PS C:\Users\i> where.exe git
C:\cygwin64\bin\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

Action: cygwin git rename git.exe -> git.exe.old

When solving an error

```
PS C:\cygwin64\bin> where.exe git
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

C:\Users\i\Documents\app\dev>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 3.9.0-22.0.pre.102, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1413], locale en-US)
[✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
[✓] Connected devices (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!
```